# Build specific where condition using CDbCriteria in Yii

Tags: yii

How can I build condition like the one below with CDbCriteria?

```
(
   title LIKE :yc0 
   OR 
   description LIKE :yc0 
   OR 
   tags LIKE :yc0
) 
AND 
(
   user=:yc1 
   OR 
   user=:yc2
)
```

I want to do this using only two methods of CDbcriteria, ie, compare() and addSearchCondition()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like the below. I'm assuming you'll want `%` wildcards around the LIKE value:

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$Criteria->addCondition('title LIKE :value OR description LIKE :value OR tags LIKE :value');
$Criteria->addCondition('user = :user1 OR user = :user2');

$Criteria->params = array(
    ':value' => '%'.$value.'%',
    ':user1' => $user1,
    ':user2' => $user2,
);

$YourModels = YourModel::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```

Or, if you want to use `addSearchCondition` and `compare`:

```
$value = 'foo';
$user1 = 1;
$user2 = 2;

$Criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$Criteria->addSearchCondition('title', $value, true, 'OR', 'LIKE');
$Criteria->addSearchCondition('description', $value, true, 'OR', 'LIKE');
$Criteria->addSearchCondition('tags', $value, true, 'OR', 'LIKE');

$Criteria->compare('user', array($user1, $user2));

$YourModels = YourModel::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```

Comment: I want to use addSearchCondition and compare methods of CDbcriteria. Can you suggest solution by those?